# How to update a field in rethinkdb documents based on its old value

Tags: rethinkdb

I have documents like the following in a database:

```
{
"email":  "abc1234" ,
"id":  "0ff9115c-44a8-4a9e-a2c1-f6f5d2ac5219" ,
"name":  "awesome dude" ,
}
```

There are multiple documents with the above form.

I want to add a string to the email field, say `@stackoverflow.com`. That is, after the update the above should become:

```
{
"email":  "abc1234@stackoverflow.com" ,
"id":  "0ff9115c-44a8-4a9e-a2c1-f6f5d2ac5219" ,
"name":  "awesome dude" ,
}
```

How do I do this in rethinkdb? I tried the following the data explorer:

```
r.db("monopolyApp").table("users").update({
  email2: r.row("email") + "@stackoverflow.com"
})
```

However, that changes every email address to:

```
"r.row("email")@stackoverflow.com"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`.add` command](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/add/).

Just modify your query to:

```
r.db("monopolyApp").table("users").update({
  email2: r.row("email").add("@stackoverflow.com")
})
```

And you should be set!

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I assumed that `add()` was only for numerical procedures.